# Vive SteamVR Stereo Rendering mirror doesn't reflect lineRenderer lines steadily

Tags: unity, 3d, htc-vive, steam-vr

I'm creating a SteamVR game in Unity. I'm using the [Vive SteamVR Stereo Rendering Toolkit](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/vive-stereo-rendering-toolkit-71255) to create the mirror effect. I also wrote a script to render three lines between headset, and two controllers, with `lineRenderer`. The lines are working fine, but in the mirror reflection, I can only see the lines rendered one at the time, as opposed to all three lines visible at the same time. Why is that?

Edit 1:

Add an image of what I see:

[image]

In my game, I used three balls to represent the headset, the left controller and the right controller. I see the lines between all three lines constantly (even though you can't see the ball in the headset obviously and the lines between the left/right controllers to the headset are clipped, which is fine...), but I can only see one line at a time in the reflection, either the line between the head and left controller or the line between the head and the right controller. For example, if I move the left controller, the line between the head and the left controller in the reflection is working, while the other disappear in the reflection. Also, the line between the left and right controllers never appear in the reflection.

Edit 2:

Add another image to explain what I want vs what I have now:

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you're seeing in each case?

Comment: @DMGregory here is the image. hope it's clear. if not, let me know and I can clarify further.

Comment: @DMGregory also add another diagram to explain it better